# How to do a SQL query that counts a word that appears in a string column with a join and group by?

Tags: sql

I want to count the amount of times that the word "completed" occurs in a info column. But the problem is that I want to put it with a group by and join. Here is the example tables:

Jobs
[job table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIUTg.png)

Groups
[group table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNQog.png)

I want something like this:
[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5TsO.png)

I was thinking of a query like this:

`Select j.Name, gName From   Jobs as j Inner join groups as g On j.groupID = g.groupID Group by g.Name, j.name'`

So how can I count the amount of times "completed" occurs for each row of my results?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS: SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a conditional `SUM` aggregate that sums the flags of `true` or 1, analogous to conditional count. Below includes alternative expressions:

- Using `LIKE` if column is open-ended and needs string search.
- Using `=` if column is restricted to consistent values as image suggests. Do note: equality `=` is more efficient than `LIKE`.
- Using `CASE` for those DBMS's that do not support direct `SUM` on a logical condition such as SQL Server.

```sql
SELECT gName AS groupName
     , j.Name AS jobName
     , SUM(j.info LIKE '%completed%') AS NumberOfCompleted1
     , SUM(j.info = 'Is completed') AS NumberOfCompleted2
     , SUM(CASE 
              WHEN j.info = 'Is completed'
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
           END) AS NumberOfCompleted3

FROM Jobs AS j 
INNER JOIN groups AS g 
   ON j.groupID = g.groupID 

GROUP BY g.Name
       , j.name
```